# Audio not playing in an application with setreuid() & setgid(), but works with sudo -u command

Tags: linux, c, alsa, pulse-audio, multiple-users

I have a Arch Linux system with alsa and pulseaudio configured. alsa is set to use pulseaudio default device. Pulseaudio is rumming with tcp module enabled on 127.0.0.1 and anonymous set to true. The system has 2 users user1 (standard user) and user2 (ststem user). I have tried `speakertest` on both users and both users are able to access the speakers.

I have a commandline audio player that is working fine on user1. I have written a `wrapper` program that does `setreuid()` and `setregid()` to user2 and then `exec()`s the audio player to play a audio file. I have provided the `wrapper` binary with `SUID` and `SGID` permissions `sudo chmod 6555 wrapper`.

When I run the audio player as user1 normally (without wrapper), I can hear the audio from the speakers.When I run the audio player normally using `sudo -u user2 audioplay <file>` from user1's shell it works fine as well.

However, *when I use the wrapper from user1's shell like `wrapper <file>`, no audio is heared from the speakers. What is going wrong when the wrapper exec()s the player?*

**Surprisingly, when I try `sudo -u user2 wrapper <file>`, I am able to listen to the audio again...**